# Converting Images through Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I am trying to convert the images using terminal to pdf. THough All my Images are of same size. But when I convert it to pdf Some of images are of correct size but some are too small to read. I want all of same size.

```
convert *.jpg mynewfile.pdf
```

I have also tried

```
convert  -resize 1273X899 *.jpg  myfile.pdf
```

But issue is same when I check image separately they are of same size.

Answer (score 0):

The convert command can also quickly resize an image.The following command asks ImageMagick to resize an image to 200 pixels in width and 100 pixels in height:

```
convert example.png -resize 200×100 example.png
```

Comment: I want to batch resize and even I have tried this one check above. Even all images are of same size.